# Table 'cf_usage.app_usage_period' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

mysql> REPAIR TABLE cf_usage.app_usage_period;

```
+---------------------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table                     | Op     | Msg_type | Msg_text                                                            |
+---------------------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| cf_usage.app_usage_period | repair | Warning  | InnoDB: Tablespace is missing for table 'cf_usage/app_usage_period' |
| cf_usage.app_usage_period | repair | Error    | Table 'cf_usage.app_usage_period' doesn't exist                     |
| cf_usage.app_usage_period | repair | status   | Operation failed                                                    |
+---------------------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

How can this be repaired???

We have tried to repair to no avail...

```
mysql> use cf_usage;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> show tables;
+--------------------------------------+
| Tables_in_cf_usage                   |
+--------------------------------------+
| app_usage_event                      |
| app_usage_event_back                 |
| app_usage_event_backup_for_sequence  |
| app_usage_event_service_status       |
| app_usage_period                     |
| app_usage_period_audit               |
| app_usage_period_backup              |
| app_usage_period_view                |
| browser_apps                         |
| insights_events                      |
| newrelic_apps                        |
| newrelic_job_status                  |
| queued_app_usage_event               |
| queued_app_usage_event_backup        |
| queued_service_usage_event           |
| schema_version                       |
| service_usage_event                  |
| service_usage_event_service_status   |
| service_usage_period                 |
| service_usage_period_backup_201710   |
| service_usage_period_backup_201710_B |
| task_usage_period_view               |
+--------------------------------------+
22 rows in set (0.00 sec)
 Table shows in contents above...
```

We have had to ZIP up the .ibd file

Comment: Try using MySQL Workbench for this sort of thing, otherwise its like using notepad to do spreadsheet work.  Download here -->https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Comment: Side note you say you zipped up the database file .. did you unzip it before using it ?  Surely you did just had to make sure, as I've never tried it, but I suspect you can't operate the idb while its inside a zip.